# Nginx two servers were invoked when processing 1 request

Tags: http, nginx

Seeing this in nginx logs:

```
"upstream": "52.86.112.192:443, 52.86.78.197:443",
"upstream_response_time": "7.005, 7.016",
```

The documentation of nginx says:

```
If several servers were contacted during request processing, 
their addresses are separated by commas, 
e.g. “192.168.1.1:80, 192.168.1.2:80, unix:/tmp/sock”.
```

Unfortunately it is not clear to me how can two servers be invoked when processing 1 request? This is w/o internal redirects? Was it a retry after the first attempt failed?

The DNS query returns two A records:

```
xxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 54.84.139.107
xxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 52.71.207.21
```

Does it mean, than nginx does a retry for every failed request automatically? Or can it be configured? (this is AWS so the IP's of the load balancers are changing constantly)

Comment: This is for 1 request, sorry, I clarified my question, underlining that it is 1 request, not two. HTML and static assets are being accessed via multiple requests.

Comment: Questions about server configurations and networking should be on http://serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Rob, will ask there.

Comment: Voted myself to close the question.

Comment: Here it is, in case anyone will wonder the same: http://serverfault.com/questions/761924/nginx-two-servers-were-invoked-when-processing-1-request